# Material design spinner in markup but without styles

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

As the title states, the spinner is in my markup, but without styles or is at least not visible. Why? It should be a straight import of the component, there's very little styles added to the project so far, none that should affect this component.

[image]

component.html

```
<mat-spinner color="primary" value="100"></mat-spinner>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ...
  ],
```

styles.scss

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;


$custom-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette, 800, 900, 500);
$custom-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$brown-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$custom-theme: mat.define-dark-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $custom-primary,
      accent: $custom-accent,
    ),
  )
);

.custom-theme {
  @include mat.button-theme($custom-theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the progress spinner theme if you're not using a material prebuilt theme.

styles.scss

```
.custom-theme {
  @include mat.button-theme($custom-theme);
  @include mat.progress-spinner-theme($custom-theme); <------ here
}
```